# Linear Mixed Model: Comparison of the effects of two continuous independent variables on one continuous dependent variable in a longitudinal design

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, panel-data

I have data from a longitudinal study, more specifically MRI data and the performance on a neuropsychological test at two time points. My research question relates to the relationship of gray matter change and change in performance on the neuropsychological measure - I would like to test whether gray matter change in brain region A is more strongly related to change in my neuropsychological measure than gray matter change in brain region B. To do this, I thought about using a Linear Mixed Model.

1. I'm not quite familiar with this method yet, but I think that I would have to compare the two regression slopes by integrating an interaction term (probably "brain region A:brain region B:time"?), right?
2. Is this a good method or is there a better approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With only two time points you can't look at change within-subject, only group-level change. You're on the right track with an interaction, but you need to combine the two regions into a single variable, and then create a new variable that indicates which region it is. I'm not sure about the interaction with time, but I think you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to proceed, depending on your idea about how the gray-matter values are associated with the neuropsychological test results.

It sounds like you think that the *change* in neuropsychological test results is going to be associated with *changes* in gray matter within brain regions A and/or B. Modeling that is just an extension of a paired *t*-test. The *change* in test results would be the single outcome measure for each individual (like in a paired *t*-test), and the *changes* in `brain_region_A`, in `brain_region_B`, and perhaps an interaction between the changes, would be predictors in the model. That wouldn't require a mixed model at all, as there's effectively only one observation per individual.

Alternatively, you could model the 2 individual test results along with corresponding values for the *amounts* of gray matter in `brain_region_A`, in `brain_region_B`, and their interaction. That is, for all of your variables, evaluate the values at each measurement time rather than the *changes* in values between measurement times. That could be done with a mixed model, assigning random intercepts to the individuals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I decided that I want to look at the changes from T1 to T2 (T1-T2) in the brain regions and in the neuropsychological test results. Do you think I would be able to conduct a regression or a SEM to find out whether grey matter in brain region A is a better predictor than grey matter in brain region B? My hypothesis is that that's gonna be the case regarding the neuropsychological test results. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @MarieFreiheit yes, but I recommend that you consult with a local statistical expert who has experience with MRI data (which I understand can be tricky; I don't have personal experience with such data). I suspect that changes in gray matter over time will be correlated between regions A and B, so it might not be possible to distinguish very well between the regions in their associations with outcome (change in neuropsychological measure). You don't know, however, until you try.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're totally right. So hypothetically I could conduct a regression and then compare effect sizes to test my hypothesis?

Comment: @Freiheit yes, but again consider consulting with a local statistic expert. There are many different measures of "[effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size)" and you want to make sure that you choose one that actually accomplishes what you wish.